# Can't update other rows in an Informix table when uncommitted insert

Tags: informix

Below int_nwn table has 1,0 status records five for each.
Tried to insert 11th row which has status 0 and not going to commit.

```
nwn@tests$echo "select count(*) from  int_nwn where status = 1" | dbaccess mydb

Database selected.
      (count(*))
               5
1 row(s) retrieved.
Database closed.

nwn@test$echo "select count(*) from  int_nwn where status = 0" | dbaccess mydb

Database selected.
      (count(*))
               5
1 row(s) retrieved.
Database closed.

nwn@test$
nwn@test$now inserting a row with uncommit^C
nwn@test$
nwn@test$echo "select count(*) from  int_nwn" | dbaccess mydb

Database selected.


  252: Cannot get system information for table.

  113: ISAM error:  the file is locked.
Error in line 1
Near character position 29


Database closed.

nwn@test$
```

Now table has a lock and trying update the un-commited row which has seq='965155500’ and return the same error as your screenshot.

```
nwn@test$
nwn@test$
nwn@test$echo "update int_nwn set ret_info='pending' where seq='965155500'" | dbaccess mydb

Database selected.
  245: Could not position within a file via an index.
  144: ISAM error: key value locked
Error in line 1
Near character position 59
Database closed.

nwn@test$
nwn@test$
```

Now trying to update other status 0 records five.  And it ended with an error.

```
nwn@test$
nwn@test$echo "update int_nwn set status=1 where status=0" | dbaccess mydb

Database selected.
  244: Could not do a physical-order read to fetch next row.
  107: ISAM error:  record is locked.
Error in line 1
Near character position 42
Database closed.

nwn@test$
```

Even though the above update failed and the table has the lock below, the update was successful:

```
nwn@test$echo "update int_nwn set status=1 where seq in (select seq from int_nwn where status=0)" | dbaccess mydb

Database selected.
5 row(s) updated.
Database closed.

nwn@test$
nwn@test$
nwn@test$
nwn@test$echo "select count(*) from  int_nwn" | dbaccess mydb

Database selected.
  252: Cannot get system information for table.
  113: ISAM error:  the file is locked.
Error in line 1
Near character position 29
Database closed.

nwn@test$
```

It seems that I can’t update the above table rows by selecting them via a "duplicates allowed" column name, and it is successful when selecting the rows going to be updated via a unique column. Can someone explain the theory behind this? What is the reason to fail "update int_nwn set status=1 where status=0" and yet allow "update int_nwn set status=1 where seq in (select seq from int_nwn where status=0)" to succeed. This table has row-level locking mode.

##################################

Please check below more informations

#############schema###################

```
create table "informix".int_nwn
  (
    seq serial not null ,
    col1 decimal(1),
    col2 char(100),
    col3 char(1),
    col4 char(2),
    col5 char(15),
    msi char(15),
    col6 char(300),
    col7 datetime year to second,
    col8 datetime year to second,
    status char(2),
    col9 char(20),
    ret_info char(800)
  )
  fragment by round robin in dbsp1 , dbsp2 , dbsp3 , dbsp4

  extent size 1048064 next size 524032 lock mode row;



create index "informix".idx_int_nwn_06_1 on "informix"
    .int_nwn (status) using btree  in idxdbs;
create index "informix".idx_int_nwn_06_2 on "informix"
    .int_nwn (msi) using btree  in idxdbs;
create unique index "informix".idx_int_nwn_06_3 on "informix"
    .int_nwn (seq) using btree  in idxdbs;
```

#############version###################

```
nwn@test$echo "SELECT DBINFO('version','full') FROM SysTables WHERE Tabid = 1" | dbaccess mydb

Database selected.
(constant)
IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 11.70.FC8W1XI
1 row(s) retrieved.
Database closed.
```

##########OS version ###################

```
nwn@test$cat /etc/release
                            Oracle Solaris 11.3 SPARC
  Copyright (c) 1983, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
                            Assembled 05 October 2017
```

###########table/db more information ###########

```
nwn@test$echo "select nrows, ncols, rowsize from systables where tabname='int_nwn'" | dbaccess mydb

Database selected.
         nrows  ncols rowsize
10.00000000000     13    1277
1 row(s) retrieved.
Database closed.
 

nwn@test$echo "SELECT name, is_logging, is_buff_log, is_ansi FROM sysdatabases WHERE name='mydb';" | dbaccess sysmaster

Database selected.

name         huw
is_logging   1
is_buff_log  1
is_ansi      0

1 row(s) retrieved.
Database closed.
```

############# corrected update statement with char values. But behavior is same

```
nwn@test$echo "update int_nwn set status='1'  where status='0'" | dbaccess mydb

Database selected.
  245: Could not position within a file via an index.
  144: ISAM error: key value locked
Error in line 1
Near character position 47

Database closed.

nwn@test$echo "update int_nwn set status='1'  where seq in (select seq from int_nwn where status='0')" | dbaccess mydb

Database selected.
5 row(s) updated.
Database closed.
```

#########################################################################

this is what second session doing at `"nwn@test$now inserting a row with uncommit^C"`

```
SQL:   New  Run  Modify  Use-editor  Output  Choose  Save  Info  Drop  Exit
Run the current SQL statements.

----------------------- mydb@testdb ----------- Press CTRL-W for Help --------

begin work;

insert into int_nwn(
seq,
col1,
col2,
col3,
col4,
col5,
msi,
col6,
col7,
col8,
status,
col9,
ret_info)

values(
'965155500',
 5.000000,
        'XXXXXX',
       '0',
       '40',
           '413012624547422',
         '3232423423',
      'xxxxx',
   '2020-12-02 18:23:48',
  '2020-12-02 18:23:53',
         '0',
    'XXXX',
       'Operation Successful');



 1 row(s) inserted.
```

Comment: Check the set explain output for the update statements, I'm guessing the update that fails is doing a sequential scan, so it will hit the uncommited insert and get a locking error, but the update that works is using an index and doesn't encounter the locked row from the uncommited insert.

Comment: Which version of Informix are you using?  (Run: `echo "SELECT DBINFO('version','full') FROM SysTables WHERE Tabid = 1" | dbaccess mydb` to get the server's version.). On which platform.  What is the logging mode of the database?  It probably isn't MODE ANSI, but is it logged or unlogged?  Can you provide an outline schema of the table?  What is the number of columns in the table?  The number of rows (is it just the 10 rows)?  The size of each row?  (The information is available from `systables` — `nrows`, `ncols`, `rowsize`.)  Is there any other activity on the table?  What indexes are on it?

Comment: First observation: Informix 11.70 went out of service at the end of September 2020.  Ideally, you should upgrade to 14.10; 12.10 would be acceptable, but will go out of service much sooner than 14.10 will.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thankyou for that suggestion. We are planning to do that upgrade near future.

Comment: Second observation: the table contains `status char(2),` but your SQL treats it as if it were an integer.  Fortunately for you, Informix is good at converting values to the requisite type.  I doubt if this has an impact on your query, but it is surprising.

Comment: Third observation: your table must normally hold vast numbers of rows to warrant using a million KiB for the first extent size and half a million KiB when a new extent is needed, and to fragment it by round-robin across 4 dbspaces..  The row size (1277) is big enough that you only get one row per page (because Informix on Solaris uses 2 KiB pages — for ancient historical reasons).  Even so, ten rows are lost in a vast acreage of space.  However, excess space mostly wastes disk rather than anything more serious.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I added the update by changing integer 1 , 0 to char values to clear the second observation

Comment: @JonathanLeffler actually this is not the actual table. actual table have more rows and should capable to handle more load. For this particular problem I created dummy table with 10 rows to narrow down the locking issue. That's how large extend size appeared

Comment: With only ten rows, it is likely that the UPDATE statements working with just `status` do a sequential scan, as @jrenaut suggested.  And the sequential scan runs into a lock, and hence fails.  For 10 rows, the index on `status` is not likely to be used.  The question becomes: why is any row in the table locked?  And that is not clear. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ The statements you execute are run in new sessions each time (a new invocation of `dbaccess`), so each of those sessions is independent of the others. Any locks held are released when the statement completes because you're using a database with buffered logging and no explicit transaction management, so each statement is a self-contained transaction.  So, it appears that some other process has the table open and has at least one row locked, but it holds onto the lock(s) for a long time.  You probably need to track that other process down. _[…continued 2…]_

Comment: @JonathanLeffler In here I explicitly locked the table by creating a insert statement with begin work and I did not commit entire time it in a separate session. This behavior happen on the actual table also because we can see some rows are visible in dirty read mode for long time and not visible for normal read. We guess some inserting interfaces are failing their connection while doing its insertion and before do the commit.

Comment: _[…continuation 2…]_ When you come back with "but there isn't another process accessing the table", the debugging gets to be tricky.  At that point, you should normally contact Informix support (assuming you have support), but (as I understand it) that is no longer an option because the product is out of service, unless your organization bought extended support.

Comment: That's kinda critical information to leave out of the question, don't you think?  Yes, you'll run into locks if there are processes which insert but do not commit — so, a process which does an explicit `BEGIN WORK`, then inserts data, and does not execute `COMMIT WORK` will indeed mess up the whole system.  The fix is 'obvious' — ensure that processes do not hold long-duration locks, even by accident.  You should commit as soon as possible, or defer starting the transaction for as long as possible so that you can commit as soon as possible.  Without knowing more about the other process, …

Comment: @JonathanLeffler since this is testing table . this table only has two sessions. one is uncommitted inserting session and other one is updating sessions as displayed in this description

Comment: OK; and your testing has demonstrated that the uncommitted insertion can screw things up royally.  Your question mentions `now inserting a row with uncommit^C` but doesn't show what's really going on there.  It is not clear what you were doing.  You might want to investigate [LAST COMMITTED](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_11.70.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1165.htm) isolation.  However, even that won't help with update operations (INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, MERGE); it will only help with SELECT operations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225550/discussion-between-nwn-and-jonathan-leffler).

Comment: An uncommitted update holds a lock on the row that is updated.  You can 'see through' it with DIRTY READ isolation in a SELECT, or you can 'see past' it by using COMMITTED READ LAST COMMITTED in a SELECT.  But an UPDATE operation must work on the 'real' value, and is always impacted by locks.  Hence it is crucial to commit operations quickly, so that locks are not held indefinitely.  Using `SET LOCK MODE WAIT 10` (so the update will wait for up to 10 seconds for the lock) may help, but only if the other transaction commits in time. It is crucial (as I said before) to commit operations quickly.